# Help with contour integral popping up in Kramers-Kronig problem

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis

I've got a principal value integral that I'd like to evaluate, but seem to have hit a bit of a roadblock with the parameters. The integral is

$$I = P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda\gamma s^2}{(s^2-w^2)((s^2-w_o^2)^2+\lambda^2s^2)}ds \equiv P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(s)ds,$$

where the $P$ denotes the principal value integral. Instead of motivating the physical problem (linear response of dielectric), I'll just mention that we need $\lambda\gamma > 0$, and all parameters are real. I know that the six poles are

$$s_* = \pm w$$
$$s_* = (i\gamma \pm \sqrt{4w_o^2-\gamma^2})/2$$
$$s_* = (- i\gamma \pm \sqrt{4w_o^2-\gamma^2})/2.$$

Now my issue is with that square root. If I assume that $4w_o^2-\gamma^2 < 0$, then those four roots are pure imaginary, and looking at the contour in the upper half plane gives (for either sign of $\gamma$)

$$I = 2\pi i\sum_{s_*} Res[f(s_*)] = \frac{\pi\gamma(w_o^2-w^2)}{(w^2-w_o^2)^2+\gamma^2w^2}$$

I know that the integral must go to zero on the arc, but have just assumed that it does on the bumps at $s = \pm w$ (why is that true? I'm not sure at the moment). However, if I assume $4w_o^2-\gamma^2 > 0$ and repeat the same procedure, the residues give me

$$I = \frac{-i\lambda\gamma(w_o^2+w^2)}{\sqrt{4w_o^2-\gamma^2}((w^2-w_o^2)^2+\gamma^2w^2)}.$$.

Now I'm not given any information about these parameters other than $\lambda\gamma > 0$, but I know that the first expression for $I$ is the correct one. What is going on here? And why can I neglect the bumps at $s = \pm w$?

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrals over the bumps do not tend to zero, but their sum does. Due to the integrand being an even function, the integral over the upper semicircle around $-w$ is equal to the integral over the lower semicircle around $w$. We get two semicircles around $w$ traversed in opposite directions, the integrals over which tend to $\pi i$ times the residue at $w$ and $-\pi i$ times the residue at $w$, because the contribution from the regular part of the Laurent series is negligible.

Let $P(s) = (s^2 - w_o^2)^2 + \lambda^2 s^2$ and assume $\lambda > 0 $. If $4 w_o^2 - \lambda^2 \geq 0$, the roots of $P$ in the upper half-plane are $(i \lambda \pm \sqrt {4 w_o^2 - \lambda^2})/2$. If $4 w_o^2 - \lambda^2 < 0$, the roots of $P$ in the upper half-plane are $i (\lambda \pm \sqrt {\lambda^2 - 4 w_o^2})/2$, the same as in the first case. Calculating the residues gives
$$\operatorname{v.\!p.}
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {\lambda s^2} {(s^2 - w^2) P(s)} ds =
\frac {\pi (w_o^2 - w^2)} {(w_o^2 - w^2)^2 + \lambda^2 w^2}.$$

Comment: Hi Maxim, thanks for the comments. Wow, I had my $\pm$ in the wrong place, *face palm*. Thank you!